# Rendering Angularjs Template from within controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-template, angularjs-templates

Suppose I have following angularjs template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tmp">
<li>    
{{firstname}} {{lastname}}</li>
</script>
```

and I have two textboxes and a save button like

```
<input name="firstname" type="text"/>
<input name="lastname" type="text"/>
<button name="save" text="save"/>
```

when user enters values in firstname and lastname textboxes and press on save button I want these two values to be passed to the template and resultant html should be appended to an existing `ul`. How can I do it with angular?

Comment: you want to open a modal window?

Comment: no, i just want the values entered in form to be passed to template somehow and resultant html of template should append to an existing `ul` element that is present on the page.

Comment: you can change the state and pass the values to that state controller using services or as state params (if you using ui-router)

Comment: Is it not possible to just use an `ng-repeat` directive in your `ul` instead? It would be a lot easier.

Comment: @bmceldowney yes, its easier but I don't have list of all names in the beginning. the user will keep adding firstnames and lastnames by pressing save button.

Comment: That's fine, `ng-repeat` handles dynamic data just fine.

Comment: can u please write down an example for me. this is just my 3rd day with angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a directive to dynamically compile your template and append it to the `ul` when someone hits the save button, but that's basically the whole purpose of `ng-repeat`.

Here's how it can work with an `ng-repeat` instead:

```js
angular.module('main', []);

angular.module('main').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.names = [];
  
 $scope.save = function () {
  $scope.names.push({first: $scope.firstname, last: $scope.lastname});
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="main" ng-controller='MainCtrl'>

  <input name="firstname" type="text" ng-model='firstname'/>
  <input name="lastname" type="text"ng-model='lastname'/>
  <button name="save" text="save" ng-click='save()'>save</button>
  
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat='name in names'>{{name.first}}   {{name.last}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. great answer. Can u please tell me how I can attach edit and delete links with it.

Comment: Well, you've got an array that you're storing the results in, so you just need some UI elements that allow you to execute some `$scope` functions that modify items in that array. I suggest using `ng-click` directives to wire that up.

Comment: Ok, few things to ask. you haven't initialized app using `angular.module` and you have left `ng-app` directive to empty. can u please explain it a little bit

Comment: It's a bad practice to set up code that way but it works for quick examples. I've edited my snippet to avoid confusion.

Comment: I have created a plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/77yxnpmx6rQXAhzFKcyN?p=preview with delete link and relevant delete function in controller but when data gets deleted the delete link does not disappear.

Comment: Maybe there's an edit that didn't get saved? I'm not seeing the delete functionality.